# How to repeat the grouped filed horizontally (jasper report)

Tags: jasper-reports

DB Table - RunRecord

```
Name      Student_ID   Meter(m)   Time(s)
ABC       1016         100        13   

ABC       1016         200        26

ACB       1017         100        15

BAA       1018         100        18

BAA       1018         200        22

BBB       1019         100        14

CDE       1020         200        22

CDE       1020         100        14
```

What should I do so that I can get the following result in Jasper Report?

```
                      Student Run Record

                  ABC           ACB           BAA        BBB         CDE
100M              13            15            18         14          14
200M              26                          22                     22
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by using a **`crosstab`** element.

I used the query as provided by you, I have in my sample these fields:

- Name: String
- Meter: Long
- Time: Long

Drag and drop the **`crosstab`** from the Palette into the summary band of the report in the Report Designer, a wizard will pop up.

Follow the wizard:

- Select the dataset that holds the query.
- Configure as rows **Meter** with grouping set to *unique*, as column you choose **Name** with grouping also set to  *unique*.
- As measure you use **Time**, and change the aggregator to *Sum* (anything but *count*, as you only have one value per student and distance the *sum* will be the same as the value).

Once the crosstab is added click in the Report Inspector and expand the crosstab, click on row groups > Meter and in the Properties panel select as **`Total Position:None`**. Same for Column Groups > Name.

The output will be then as shown in the image below.

[image: draft report]

In order to get the output closer to what you drafted in your query:

- In the Report Inspector select Row Groups > Meter, in the Properties panel change the Bucket Value Class to `java.lang.String`. Then in the designer edit the field that holds `$V{Meter}` and change it to  `$V{Meter} + "m"` to have output *100m* instead of *100*.
- In order to hide *0*, click in the Designer on the field that holds the measure and change it from `$V{TimeMeasure}` to `$V{TimeMeasure} == 0 ? null : $V{TimeMeasure}`. In the Properties Panel check the box for property *Blank when null*.

[image: finished report]

Answer (score 0):

Change the bucket expression of report row group. Make the bucket expression by concatenation of few fields. eg:

```
<bucket class="java.lang.String">
    <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{field1}+""+$F{field2}]]></bucketExpression>
</bucket>
```